# Android imported Bitmaps too large on Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, scale

I'm developing a game. My Canvas should scale to screen height (1920x1080 on the emulator phone). But when I import images from Photoshop (1920x1080), they are way larger than the phone.

Why does this happen? Is my Canvas secretly a smaller size than I think? Is AndroidStudio importing images way larger than they should be?

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

canvas = view.getHolder().lockHardwareCanvas();
canvas.rotate(90);
```

I tried canvas.scale but it made my entire screen just a color gradient at whatever values I input for width and height. Also what does canvsa.density do? Thanks very much to whoever takes their time to answer this

Comment: "But when I import images from Photoshop (1920x1080), they are way larger than the phone" -- could you expand your [mcve] to show how you are using these images and what exactly you mean by "import"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place your images from Photoshop in somewhere res/drawable, you should move them to res/drawable-nodpi to avoid re-scaling.

Comment: Thanks for  the reply, but I dont have a  nodpi folder. Do i just make one with that name or how can I set that up?

Comment: @FiveJungYetNoSmite Yes, you can just create drawable-nodpi directory right under the res directory.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!